# How to get the coordinates of a route without having to clear the previous drawn route?

Tags: android, skmaps

By using the method

```
SKRouteManager.getInstance().calculateRoute(route);
```

the previously drawn map is deleted and replaced. Is it possible to get a list of coordinates for a route without having to delete the route currently drawn on the map and not having to create a route and cache it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate multiple routes without displaying them on the map by setting the [isRouteExposed](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/3.0.0/com/skobbler/ngx/routing/SKRouteSettings.html#isRouteExposed()) parameter to false.

I believe that once you display a route on the map, any call to calculateRoute (even if not shown on the map) will make the route on map disappear. A potential workaround this would be to use the [online routing service](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/web#sec2).